# refresh div after X seconds using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery

i found [this code](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html) for refresh my div using jquery. this worked but i have any problem. this plugin always refreshed my div and print result. this bad idea. i need to print `div` and `result` when `result != 0`. in my i.e jquery print `0` in result div. any way for this solutions ? thanks

jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval( 
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);    
<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
```

record_count.php ( very simple ) result = 0

```
0
```

Comment: Just FYI: I remove the superfluous code from the PHP file, you can actually use a static file that's why I removed the tag as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $.get('record_count.php', null, function(data) {
        if (data != "0") {
            $('#load_tweets').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }, "html")
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'record_count.php',
        sucsess:function(data){
        if(data!=0)    
            $('#load_tweets').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}, 10000);​
```